# deriving the distribution of Y having information about X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A child who has swallowed a pin of length 4cm is X-rayed. THe pin appears on the X-ray film as shown below, the length of the image being y, an observation on the random variable Y. The pin is at an angle $x$, $0\le x \le \frac \pi2$, to the normal to the film, this being an observation on the random variable X.

If all angles X are equally likely, derive the distribution of Y. What is the mean length of the image on the film?

(I don't know how to attach the image accompanying the problem) but so far what I have done is say that the c.d.f. of X is $$F_x(x) =\begin{cases} &0,
 \text {if $x\lt$ 0} \\ & x, \text { if $0\le x\le \frac \pi2$}\\&1 , \text {if $x\gt \frac \pi2$}\\ \end{cases}$$

so then based on that I need to somehow figure out the distribution of Y. Will it be something to do with $\frac \pi4$ and arcsin? I think that based on the picture and basic geometry from looking at it, but I am really not sure I am even on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't do pictures either so I hope I can describe things.

The normal vector is the line pointing straight out of the camera. So if the nail were parallel to the normal $(X=0)$ you wouldn't be able to see it's length at all, it would just be a dot $(Y=0)$.

If the nail were perpendicular to the normal $(X=\frac\pi 2)$  you would be able to see the whole length $(Y=4)$.

A little bit of trigonometry and you can extend that to $Y = 4\sin(X)$.

So, you know the distribution of $X$, it's uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,\frac\pi 2)$ and you should know how to calculate the expectation(mean) of a function of $X$.

Let me know if you're still stuck.